# Replace text in post from cvs

Tags: custom-post-types, plugins, php, custom-field

I have constructed a post template that i want to use to all post. I use visual composer and some add ons . I need to create post with vcs file but i don't know hot to organize the cvs inside to do that what i want, when i will upload cvs using some plugins out there that i have searched for.

**Example**. The cvs to use post template that i have created but also to replace : The result (1), the date (2), the text HOME (3) , the text AWAY (4), the text league and stadium (5,6) or more data.

[image]

I want to use it for creating multiply post with different data, i have searched at google and i found that data should look like this [image]

but how to make it to replace and to use the post template, is there any plugin or code or to use custom fields . Please help me I'm in big struggle

Answer (score 1):

Best thing to do is to write your own CSV import php file. By using functions like wp_insert_post() you can insert the data from the csv file as a new post in the wordpress database.

If you're not a coder, which I'm sensing, you can try this plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-ultimate-csv-importer/.

The free function offers everything you're looking for. The pro version offers more in terms of custom fields support. But assuming your custom fields are default wordpress custom fields, the free version will do.